# FullPage.js link nav <li> to slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js library for my website, It's going great so far but I got stuck with this issue:

I am trying to link the nav buttons to slides, so when I click on "About" it slide to About Slide, not SCROLL!!

Since my website is one page section with 5 slides, instead of linking to sections, I want to link to slides. While I was reading the documentary of the library, it says to use "data-anchor" for that but it didn't work.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

NOTE: Live demos won't work on JSFiddle or CodePen since the scripts are external.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Shukri</title>
<!--- Bootstrap.css --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!--- Bootstrap Theme --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!--- style.css --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<!--- Responsive.css --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />
    <!--- Other --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highslide/highslide-ie6.css"/>
</head>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------->

<body>


<style>
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    nav {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: white;
    }

    a[title] {
        color: #b70000;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    a:link, a:visited {
            color: #b70000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    a:hover, a:visited:hover {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #b70000 !important;
        }

    #menu li a:Hover {
        color: white;
    }

    .about-section div h2, .about-section div h5, .about-section div span {
        color: red;
    }

    .contact-section span {
        color: #b70000;
    }

    .contact-section a {
        color: black;
    }

    .contact-section a:Hover {
        color: white;
    }

</style>

<aside class="container-fluid" id="menu">
    <nav class="navbar-nav navbar navbar-fixed-top col-lg-2">
        <div class="navbar"><img style="padding-top: 20px;" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></div>
        <ul class="nav menu nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-item slide1"><a href="#slide1" title="HomePage">Home</a></li><br>
                <li class="nav-item slide2"><a href="#slide2" title="About Shukri">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item slide3"><a href="#slide3" title="Projects">Our Projects</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item slide4"><a href="#slide4" title="Employees">Our Employees</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item slide5"><a href="#slide5" title="Contqct Information">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>




<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">
        <div class="container">
    <section class="home-section">
        <div>
            STUFF
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">
<div class="container">
    <section class="about-section">
        <div>
            <h2>About US</h2>
            <h5>INTRODUCTION</h5>

            <p><span>Great architecture</span> is not made but evolves from a mysterious alchemy of mind, efforts and technology. That’s what makes architecture alluring. The current education, infrastructures, transportation and industrialization activities around the kingdom has given architects, engineers, planners and entrepreneurs tremendous opportunities to build to suit the required paradigm favorable for building design, its management, its energy issues and operations.</p>

            <p><span>MHS Architectural Office</span> has similar vision, not only demystify technology modeling in general but also to provide tips, training and information system that will help clients/companies, other architects and engineers to achieve efficient design and aid in energy modeling, the assumptions, coordination process, including the tools and what the output means to potential design decisions. Therefore the need to identify best practices and deliver quality tools to perform in-depth performance analysis has never been greater. Reliable and consistent full-building system, energy and operational analysis are necessary to achieve increasingly aggressive performance targets in the building design and construction sectors.</p>

            <p><span>MHS Architectural Office</span> is primarily a science based team, as opposed to data-based team. It is comprised of experienced professionals in the fields of architecture, urban design, engineering, planning, IT and Information management.</p>

            <p><span>MHS Architectural Office</span> profusely adopts the latest BIM tools like the Autodesk Revit in Architecture, MEP and Structure. Being an Autodesk “Authorized Training Center” and “Authorized Accrediting Center” and networking with industry peers to simplify the design process to achieve better results in terms of efficiency, economy of time, money, efforts, and coordination which minimize the likelihood of common mishaps which otherwise is so prevalent in the conventional practices.</p>

            <p><span>As architects</span>, we have to be fearless to visualize the tomorrow, because it will be the tomorrow that decides the worthiness of what we do today. So how do we build the kind of flexibility needed into our thought process, building system, material selection, so that it bends to the future’s need?</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3">
        <div class="container">
    <section class="projects-section">
        <div>
            Nothing Here Baby...
        </div>
    </section>
</div> 
    </div>


    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4">
        <div class="container">
        <section class="employee-section">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg table">
    <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/Mohammed_H_Shoukri.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Eng. Mohammed H. Shoukri</span>
    <br>
    General Manger<br>
    Consultant Architect<br>
    20 Years experience
    </td>

    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/Mohammed_Zahiruddin_Siddiqi.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Eng. Mohammed Zahiruddin Siddiqi</span>
    <br>
    Consultant Architect<br>
    36 Years experience
    </td>
    </tr>

    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/Jurgen_Schluter.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Eng. Jurgen Schluter</span>
    <br>
    Consultant Civil<br>
    30 Years experience
    </td>

        <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/Wahbi_Mohammed_Maad.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Eng. Wahbi Mohammed Maad</span>
    <br>
    Civil Engineer<br>
    13 Years experience
    </td>

    <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/PHTO.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Eng. Abdulaziz S. Rasheedi</span>
    <br>
    Architect Engineer<br>
    2 Years experience
    </td>

    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/anas.jpg"/></th>
    <td><span>Eng. Anas Al Ahwal</span>
    <br>
    Architect Engineer<br>
    under training
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/Khalid_R_Kaddoumi.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Mr. Khalid R. Kaddoumi</span>
    <br>
    Co-ordinating marketing and<br>
    translation<br>
    36 Years experience
    </td>

    <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="imgs/Mohammed_M_Al%20Haddad.png"/></th>
    <td><span>Mr.Mohammed M. Al Haddad</span>
    <br>
    Accountant<br>
    4 Years experience
    </td>
    </table></div>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide5">
        <div class="container">
<section class="contact-section">
        <h2>Contact Info</h2>
<td width="746" valign="top" class="main_ubg"><table width="746" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="main_bg"><table width="736" height="212" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="300" valign="top"><img src="images/kroky.jpg" width="300" height="243" hspace="10"></td>
                <td width="400" valign="top" class="content"><span>Tel :</span>+966122345362<br><br>
                  <span>Fax :</span>+966126949635<br><br>
                  <span>Email :</span> <a href="mailto:info@mhs-arch.com">info@mhs-arch.com</a>
                    <br><br>
<span>Website :</span> <a href="http://www.mhs-arch.com" target="_self">http://www.mhs-arch.com</a></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
</section>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


<footer class="footer" id="footer">
    <p class="text-center navbar-fixed-bottom" style="bottom: 20px; color: #b70000; font-size: 12px;">Copyright &copy; Mohammed H Shukri Architectural Office. All rights reserved</p>
</footer>


<!--- JQuery --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- Bootstrap JS --->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--- Custom JS --->
<script src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/examples.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                //Navigation
        menu: '#menu',
        lockAnchors: true,
        anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage'],
        navigation: false,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
        showActiveTooltip: false,
        slidesNavigation: false,
        slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

        //Scrolling
        css3: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 700,
        autoScrolling: false,
        fitToSection: false,
        fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
        scrollBar: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        easingcss3: 'ease',
        loopBottom: false,
        loopTop: false,
        loopHorizontal: true,
        continuousVertical: false,
        continuousHorizontal: true,
        scrollHorizontally: true,
        interlockedSlides: false,
        dragAndMove: true,
        offsetSections: false,
        resetSliders: false,
        fadingEffect: false,
        normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
        scrollOverflow: true,
        scrollOverflowReset: false,
        scrollOverflowOptions: null,
        touchSensitivity: 15,
        normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
        bigSectionsDestination: null,

        //Accessibility
        keyboardScrolling: true,

        //Design
        controlArrows: true,
        verticalCentered: true,
        paddingTop: '3em',
        paddingBottom: '10px',
        fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
        responsiveWidth: 0,
        responsiveHeight: 0,
        responsiveSlides: true,

        //events
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){},
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
        afterRender: function(){},
        afterResize: function(){},
        afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){},
        afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){},
        onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex){}
    });
});
</script>
<script src="highslide/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // override Highslide settings here
    // instead of editing the highslide.js file
    hs.graphicsDir = '/highslide/graphics/';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the function [`moveTo`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide) of fullPage.js and add it to your own custom click events.

This will allow you to go to the section and slide you want.

[Live demo](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/doqOmY)